# Create Docker container on newly created VM with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, docker, google-compute-engine, terraform

I want to use Terrafom for the following sequence of tasks:

1. Create a VM in a common IaaS cloud (I am currently using Google Compute Engine but AWS / Azure / etc. is also fine)
2. Install Docker on that VM
3. Start a Docker container on that VM

The way this should be done is the following:

config.tf:

```
module "google_server" {
    source="google_module"
    name_machine = "server"
}
provider "docker" {
    alias="abc"
    host="tcp://${module.google_server.ip_address[0]}:2375"
}

resource "docker_container" "container" {
    provider = "docker.abc"
    ...
}
```

google_module/google_server.tf

```
provider "google" {
    ...
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "vm" {
    ...
}

output "ip_address" {
  value = "${google_compute_instance.vm.*.network_interface.0.access_config.0.assigned_nat_ip}"
}
```

However I get the following error:

```
module.docker.provider.docker.abc: Error initializing Docker client: invalid endpoint
```

If I replace `${module.google_server.ip_address[0]}` with a random IPv4 address, the error changes to a timeout.
The only way I have been able to solve my problem is by running docker through an SSH script with Terraform. Since this is not very clean, I would appreciate help.

Comment: no real google experience, but is this the public ip you are referencing? does the firewall allow for traffic on that port at the cloud level? at the vm level?

Comment: Yes it does. To verify it, I changed `${module.google_server.ip_address[0]}` to a random IP. It gives me a timeout. If the problem were the firewall, I would get a timeout here too. I can also remote execute docker on the machine once it is up.

Comment: What does `module.google_server.ip_address` look like if you output it?

Comment: I have changed the addresses. I get:
[
  76.145.70.90,
  76.145.30.120
]
if I start a single instance it is 
[
  76.145.70.90
].
To be clear, I started the instances without the docker resource / provider to output this.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer myself. This is an [open issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/4149) in the Github project for TerraForm.

The common workaround ([as described here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/17420)) is to run `TerraForm apply` with the `-target` flag once first, in order to run a multistage `apply`.

In this case it would be:

```
$ terraform apply -target=module.google_server
 -- works on target first --
$ terraform apply
 -- works on rest --
```